# Is it possible to use wildcard in the SELECT line of a sql statement?

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a table t with columns: 
x1, x2, x3, ... x100, y1, y2, y3, ... y100, z1, z2, z3, ... z100

Is there a way to select just the x variables?  I was hoping there was something like this code available: SELECT x% FROM t

The purpose of the question is to select a subset of possibly hundreds of available columns without having to explicitly name them.

Comment: Other than `SELECT *`, which selects all of them regardless of name, no.

Comment: no you can't use wildcard for column name

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What is the reason of not write `*` or to write the list of columns in select instruction?

Comment: What is wrong with `SELECT *` ?  There seems to be a bigger problem here.  Or are you saying there are x1-x100 and y1-y100 columns but you only want to select the x ones?

Comment: @overloading that seems to be, as I see... Seems he has a pattern in columns names, and he want to select only columns that starts with that pattern... but the question is not so fully understandable, to me at least!

Comment: @Monk . . . In general, no, but some databases have extensions to SQL that allow something similar.  That said, there is possibly an issue with the data model if you are repeating data in columns that should be in rows.

Comment: The SQL standard defines a single wildcard only: `*`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you point out some of the database extensions? I'm developing a custom column selector and that could be of use.

Comment: I'm with Gordon here: The desire to select a prefixed subgroup of the columns may indicate a poor data model. @Monk: Maybe you would like to explain your table design and the reasoning that led to it.

Comment: The purpose of the question is to select a subset of possibly hundreds of available columns without having to explicitly name them.  CR7SMS's answer below works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use dynamic SQL. In SQL server something like this might do the trick:

```
select 1 as x1,2 as x2,3 as x3,4 as a1,5 as a2,6 as a3 
into #table

DECLARE @Col_names nvarchar(1000) = 
(SELECT stuff((
    SELECT ', ' + cast(name as varchar(max))
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
    WHERE object_id = Object_id('tempdb..#table') --Table name goes here
            and name like 'x%' -- Column name condition goes here
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, ''));

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(1000) =
     N'select ' + @Col_names + ' from #table';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```